# how to modify the web.xml on a Jetty9 install on Pi Rasbian for CORS support?

Tags: cors, jetty, geoserver

I have a `Pi3/Raspbian` Stretch Full version where I had installed `Jetty9` using the `sudo apt-get install jetty9` and I want to use the latest `geoserver.war` with `CORS` support.

I have copied the `geoserver.war` v 2.11.2 into the `/usr/share/jetty9/webapps` folder and expected the war to be automatically expanded into a geoserver folder in that webapps folder, thereby enabling me to modify the `web.xml` file to enable CORS support.

However, it expands the war into the `/var/cache/jetty9` folder system. I had used Tomcat on a windows system so probably I have wrong expectations. I assume that if I will modify the `web.xml` file then I will need to restart the `jetty9` service but this will clear out the expanded folder and recreate it again, hence overwriting my changes.

For info, the `jetty9` root and the `geoserver` apps both work OK (but without CORS support yet).

Looking around, there seem to be more details approaches to installing `Jetty9` involving creating `/opt` folder structures etc. But it seems that direct installation of `jetty9` has more or less worked. I tried creating work folder in the `/usr/share/jetty9` folder as some have suggested but that made no difference.

I've seen some answers that talk about modifying the jetty tempdir but I'm assuming that just allows for the expansion elsewhere to prevent the tmp folders being cleared out as a background task but would not address the war being exploded each time I restart the service.

I suspect there are various ways I could get round some of these issues but I feel what I'm trying to do is fairly standard so wanted to understand the best-practice approach for the problem (for instance, I thought modifying the `jetty-webapps.xml` was valid but there is no `jetty-webapps.xml` anywhere).

Comment: duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty

Comment: Thanks Iant. That stackexchange answer covers some of the CORS elements but doesn't address the issue of the war expanding to the cache folder and hence being overridden each time I restart the jetty9 service so open to input on that part.

Comment: just edit the war file - vi will edit them just fine

Comment: Update - I've looked into the jetty9 and geoserver installs on the Pi & see that there is a jetty-servlets-9.2.21.v20170120.jar present already in the /usr/share/jetty9/lib folder so I have a couple of best practice elements that I want to clarify...
1. Should I go with the geoserver.war file or manually expand this file to manage editing the web.xml file?
2. Do I need to restart the j9 service if I make a change to the web.xml (I'm assuming I will in order for the change to be picked up on) but how do I avoid the j9 service simply exploding the war file again & overwriting my mods?